# How to simplify SQL inner joins with Group by clause for performance in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I'm using Oracle
I have a join query to fetch data from multiple tables. But this query takes longer to fetch data.

So, is there someone who can help me in writing this query in another way that takes less time?

The query is given below:

```
 SELECT CP.ACCOUNTNUMBER,GL.ACCOUNTNAME,
                CASE
                     WHEN NVL(SUM(TE.Debit * TE.BASECURRENCYEXCHANGERATE),0)-NVL(SUM(TE.Credit * TE.BASECURRENCYEXCHANGERATE),0)>0
                     THEN NVL(SUM(TE.Debit * TE.BASECURRENCYEXCHANGERATE),0) - NVL(SUM(TE.Credit * TE.BASECURRENCYEXCHANGERATE),0)
                     ELSE 0
                     END AS DEBIT,
                CASE
                     WHEN NVL(SUM(te.Credit * TE.BASECURRENCYEXCHANGERATE),0) - NVL(SUM(te.Debit * TE.BASECURRENCYEXCHANGERATE),0) > 0
                     THEN NVL(SUM(te.Credit * TE.BASECURRENCYEXCHANGERATE),0) - NVL(SUM(te.Debit * TE.BASECURRENCYEXCHANGERATE),0)
                     ELSE 0
                     END AS Credit
         FROM        CPOACCOUNTS CP
         INNER JOIN  GLACCOUNTS GL
         ON          GL.ACCOUNTID=CP.ACCOUNTID
         INNER JOIN  TRANSACTIONENTRIES TE
         ON          GL.ACCOUNTID=TE.GLACCOUNTID
         INNER JOIN  TRANSACTIONS TR
         ON          TR.TRANSACTIONID=TE.TRANSACTIONID

         WHERE       TR.DATECREATED<='13-Aug-2018'
         GROUP BY    CP.ACCOUNTNUMBER,GL.ACCOUNTNAME
         ORDER BY    CP.ACCOUNTNUMBER,GL.ACCOUNTNAME;
```

Result: 3,141 rows fetched.

So, is there someone who can help me in writing this query in another way that takes less time?

Comment: What indexes do you have? Where is the explain plan?

Comment: What is the datatype of your tr.datecreated column? If it's of Date datatype, then you should convert the date-as-a-string into a date, e.g. `to_date('13/08/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`, or maybe even `trunc(sysdate)`, if you run the query daily.

Comment: @ Boneist, tried with those functions but nothing has changed !

Comment: Please update your question to include the execution plan of the query, plus more information on your tables. E.g. is it a one-to-one relationship between gl.accountid and ate.glaccountid and also between tr.transactionid and te.transactionid?

Answer (score -1):

you can use natural join for faster performance. 
or 
there is another way to improve performance is use index on these columns.

Comment: I would advise against using a natural join instead of the inner joins the OP is using; natural joins assume that all columns that have the same name in both tables are part of the join, which may not be what is needed, and causes the query to change if an additional column is added to one of the tables that happens to have the same name as a column in the other table.